# Printing list of files by reading a list-file not working when checked for actual existence of read paths

Tags: list, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, echo

As I mentioned in Q-title, I am trying to read some file-paths, which I intend to delete later, from a list-file which contains these paths delimited by `newline` as below[ChromeJunks.lst]:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History-journal
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network Action Predictor
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network Action Predictor-journal
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Top Sites
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Top Sites-journal
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Visited Links
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Favicons
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Favicons-journal
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data-journal
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Log
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Log.old
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\QuotaManager-journal
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\QuotaManager
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\LOCK
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.bak
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Affiliation Database
```

Now this list-file is in same folder as my batch script, which is attempting to read this list-file line-by-line and check if whether these paths actually exist, and if so then print those file-paths(these file-paths I intend to delete later), the batch code as follows:

```
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist "%~dp0ChromeJunks.lst" ( set "Junks=%~dp0ChromeJunks.lst" )
for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%a in (%Junks%) do ( if exist "%%a" echo "%%a" )
endlocal && pause && exit
```

But this doesn't print any path, because I am trying to check if these paths actually exist line-by-line, with `if exist`, why ? Is it because of Env variables won't work when read from text-file ? If I remove `if exist "%%a"` then it prints just fine, but that's a deal-breaker. And **chrome(even after exited fully) doesn't delete these files** by itself, so trust me **these listed files are there** and that's why I am trying to print those.

I am at loss, can anyone help out make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file path is stored in `%%a`, `%LOCALAPPDATA%` is never expanded because regular variables are expanded before `for` loop variables (see [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133) for more details). In order to expand `%LOCALAPPDATA%` into something meaningful, we need to use `call` to perform another round of expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist "%~dp0ChromeJunks.lst" set "Junks=%~dp0ChromeJunks.lst"

for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%a in (%Junks%) do (
    call set "filename=%%~a"
    if exist "!filename!" echo !filename!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simply that you need to expand the variable first, the simplest way to do that would be to run it within another `for` loop, where the content would be sent through to another cmd instance.

If your file content is only ever going to be directories, I would advise you do it more like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Junks=%~dp0ChromeJunks.lst"
If Not Exist "%Junks%" Exit /B
For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%Junks%"
) Do For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ('Echo("%%~G"'
) Do If Exist "%%~H\*" Echo "%%~G"
Pause
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

Or maybe like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Junks=%~dp0ChromeJunks.lst"
If Not Exist "%Junks%" Exit /B
For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%Junks%"
) Do For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ('Set /P "=%%~G" 0^<NUL ^& Echo('
) Do If Exist "%%~H\*" Echo "%%~G"
Pause
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

Alternatively, for a possible mixture of files and directories, I'd do it more like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Junks=%~dp0ChromeJunks.lst"
If Not Exist "%Junks%" Exit /B
For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%Junks%"
) Do For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ('Echo("%%~G"'
) Do If "%%~aH" GEq "d" (Echo %%G is an existing directory.
) Else If "%%~aH" GEq "-" (Echo %%G is an existing file.
) Else Echo %%G does not exist.
Pause
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

or like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Junks=%~dp0ChromeJunks.lst"
If Not Exist "%Junks%" Exit /B
For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%Junks%"
) Do For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ('Set /P "=%%~G" 0^<NUL ^& Echo('
) Do If "%%~aH" GEq "d" (Echo %%G is an existing directory.
) Else If "%%~aH" GEq "-" (Echo %%G is an existing file.
) Else Echo %%G does not exist.
Pause
EndLocal
Exit /B
```